# Retrieving Data From Firestore Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an Inventory Management app for which  I tried to retrieve data from my fire store database but I am not able to get why . I created a Adapter file and and Data file and linked them with main file

My Code for Main Activity file

```
package com.example.inventorymanagment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Measure extends AppCompatActivity {

 RecyclerView recyclerView;
 ArrayList<data> itemList;
 adapter adapter;
 FirebaseFirestore db;




 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_measure);



 recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


 db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
itemList= new ArrayList<>();
adapter= new adapter(Measure.this,itemList);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

getdata();


 }

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
private void getdata() {

db.collection("Inventory").orderBy("Name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
        .addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
            if(error!=null){
                Log.e("Firestore error",error.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        for(DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()){
            if(dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                itemList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(data.class));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        });
     }

  }
```

Code for  Adapter file

```
package com.example.inventorymanagment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import  androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;



import java.util.ArrayList;

public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.MyViewHolder>{


  Context context;
  ArrayList<data> itemList;

   public  adapter(Context context, ArrayList<data>itemList)
   {
    this.context = context;
   this.itemList = itemList;
   }

@NonNull

@Override
     public adapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

  data data = itemList.get(position);
  holder.Name.setText(data.Name);
  holder.Quantity.setText(String.valueOf(data.Quantity));
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView Name, Quantity;



    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        Quantity=itemView.findViewById((R.id.quantity));
    }
}
}
```

My Code for Data file

```
  package com.example.inventorymanagment;

public class data {

 String Name;
 long Quantity;

  public data(){}

public data(String name, long quantity) {
    Name = name;
    Quantity = quantity;
 }

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public long getQuantity() {
    return Quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(long quantity) {
    Quantity = quantity;
}
  }
```

please help me find my error

Comment: Add getdata(); before setadapter call and try once.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend doing some more debugging locally and telling what specific line of code isn't doing what you expect it to do. To that end, set breakpoints on each line, run the app in a debugger, and check the value of each variable at each breakpoint. At some point you'll be "huh? that is unexpected" and that is typically the moment we can be most helpful here.

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb No change sir

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, sir, I ran my app in the debugger it says E/Firestore error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions, but I have connected my android studio with the fire base database

Comment: I recommend [searching for that error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=E%2FFirestore+error%3A+PERMISSION_DENIED%3A+Missing+or+insufficient+permissions), as it's been covered quite a few times before.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have done all the changes like changing the rules of data base but still no use , I am not getting the output

Comment: Time to pul out the debugger again and step through the code line by line, checking each variable on each line. Which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: This [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) explains why you get that error and how you can get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  In onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
     data data = itemList.get(position);
     holder.Name.setText(data.Name);
     holder.Quantity.setText(String.valueOf(data.Quantity));
```

try setting data.getName() instead of data.Name